# Video broadcast using NDI SDK 4.5 in iOS 13 not working. Receiver in LAN does not receive any video packets

Tags: ios13, xcode11

I have been trying to use NDI SDK 4.5, in a Objective-C iOS-13 app, to broadcast camera capture from iPhone device.

My sample code is in public Github repo: https://github.com/bharatbiswal/CameraExampleObjectiveC

Following is how I send `CMSampleBufferRef` sampleBuffer:

```
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

NDIlib_video_frame_v2_t video_frame;
video_frame.xres = VIDEO_CAPTURE_WIDTH;
video_frame.yres = VIDEO_CAPTURE_HEIGHT;
video_frame.FourCC = NDIlib_FourCC_type_UYVY; // kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange
video_frame.line_stride_in_bytes = VIDEO_CAPTURE_WIDTH * VIDEO_CAPTURE_PIXEL_SIZE;
video_frame.p_data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);
NDIlib_send_send_video_v2(self.my_ndi_send, &video_frame);
```

I have been using "**NewTek NDI Video Monitor**" to receive the video from network. However, even though it shows as source, the video does not play.

Has anyone used NDI SDK in iOS to build broadcast sender or receiver functionalities? Please help.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` in video settings. And `NDIlib_FourCC_type_BGRA` as FourCC in NDIlib_video_frame_v2_t.

Comment: I tried, but did not work. May be I am missing something in my code. Can you please try the same with my code from Github repo: https://github.com/bharatbiswal/CameraExampleObjectiveC

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure about your `VIDEO_CAPTURE_PIXEL_SIZE` ?

When I worked with NDI on macos I had the same black screen problem and it was due to a wrong line stride.

Maybe this can help : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1456964-cvpixelbuffergetbytesperrow?language=objc ?

Also it seems the pixel formats from core video and NDI don't match.

On the core video side you are using **Bi-Planar** Y'CbCr 8-bit 4:2:0,  and on the NDI side you are using `NDIlib_FourCC_type_UYVY` which is Y'CbCr 4:2:2.

I cannot find any **Bi-Planar** Y'CbCr 8-bit 4:2:0 pixel format on the NDI side.

You may have more luck using the following combination:

- core video: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1563591-pixel_format_identifiers/kcvpixelformattype_420ypcbcr8planarfullrange?language=objc
- NDI: NDIlib_FourCC_type_YV12

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can not use kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8PlanarFullRange. 
Unfortunately on iPhone devices, only 
kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange,
 kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange  and 
kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA 
are supported. 
These formats are output of availableVideoCVPixelFormatTypes https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideodataoutput/1387050-availablevideocvpixelformattypes

Comment: As per NDI SDK Documentation https://drive.google.com/open?id=1E0cR7fDsi7spQQzWcIJW_N0seEeux5_V, 
page 10, section  “13.3 SENDING VIDEO”, it is best to use UYVY or UYVA. 
Which out of above 3 formats available in iOS devices maps to UYVY or UYVA?

Comment: Then you may use the following combination:

- `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA `
- `NDIlib_FourCC_type_BGRA `
- `VIDEO_CAPTURE_PIXEL_SIZE  = 4` so a line stride of width*4

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you have two mistake. To use CVPixelBuffer's CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress, the CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress method must be called first. Otherwise, it returns a null pointer.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1457128-cvpixelbufferlockbaseaddress?language=objc

Secondly, NDI does not support YUV420 biplanar. (The default format for iOS cameras.) More precisely, NDI only accepts one data pointer. In other words, you have to merge the biplanar memory areas into one, and then pass it in NV12 format. See the NDI document for details.

So your code should look like this: And if sending asynchronously instead of NDIlib_send_send_video_v2, a strong reference to the transferred memory area must be maintained until the transfer operation by the NDI library is completed.

```
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
int width = (int)CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
int height = (int)CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);
OSType pixelFormat = CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(pixelBuffer);

NDIlib_FourCC_video_type_e ndiVideoFormat;
uint8_t* pixelData;
int stride;

if (pixelFormat == kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA) {
    ndiVideoFormat = NDIlib_FourCC_type_BGRA;
    pixelData = (uint8_t*)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer); // Or copy for asynchronous transmit.
    stride = width * 4;        
} else if (pixelFormat == kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange) {
    ndiVideoFormat = NDIlib_FourCC_type_NV12;
    pixelData = (uint8_t*)malloc(width * height * 1.5);
    uint8_t* yPlane = (uint8_t*)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0);
    int yPlaneBytesPerRow = (int)CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0);
    int ySize = yPlaneBytesPerRow * height;
    uint8_t* uvPlane = (uint8_t*)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1);
    int uvPlaneBytesPerRow = (int)CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1);
    int uvSize = uvPlaneBytesPerRow * height;
    stride = yPlaneBytesPerRow;

    memcpy(pixelData, yPlane, ySize);
    memcpy(pixelData + ySize, uvPlane, uvSize);
} else {
    return;
}

NDIlib_video_frame_v2_t video_frame;
video_frame.xres = width;
video_frame.yres = height;
video_frame.FourCC = ndiVideoFormat;
video_frame.line_stride_in_bytes = stride;
video_frame.p_data = pixelData;
NDIlib_send_send_video_v2(self.my_ndi_send, &video_frame); // synchronous sending.

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

// For synchrnous sending case. Free data or use pre-allocated memory.
if (pixelFormat == kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange) {
    free(pixelData);
}
```